# react native background upload says upload complete but actually not uploaded

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I am trying to upload a video from my device using react native background upload process.
But the problem I am getting is that it is showing upload completed but the video is actually not uploaded on the server

```
const options = {
      url: 'https://mydomain.co/video/',
      path: `${this.state.path}`,
      method: 'POST',
      type: 'raw',
      maxRetries: 2, 
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      notification: {
        enabled: true
      },
      useUtf8Charset: true
    }
    Upload.startUpload(options).then((uploadId) => {
      console.log('Upload started')
      Upload.addListener('progress', uploadId, (data) => {
        console.log(`Progress: ${data.progress}%`)
      })
      Upload.addListener('error', uploadId, (data) => {
        console.log(`Error: ${data.error}%`)
      })
      Upload.addListener('cancelled', uploadId, (data) => {
        console.log(`Cancelled!`)
      })
      Upload.addListener('completed', uploadId, (data) => {
        // data includes responseCode: number and responseBody: Object
        console.log('Completed!')
      })
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('Upload error!', err)
    })
```

Can any one help with what is the error with this ?

Comment: it's because you need a server to catch the video and save there!

Comment: Can you please elaborate..

Comment: you just handle the frontend stuff to upload the video, but you need a server to get the video and save it! you can find it or you just can API like https://imgbb.com/